# AngularJS, MVVM and readonly fields

Tags: c#, angularjs, mvvm

I design many of my .NET + AngularJS applications using MVVM pattern like this:

1. REST webservices passing viewmodels for specific use case (only with needed data).
2. AngularJS applicaton consuming these viewmodels and passing same viewmodels after user modifications to the webservice method supporting POST operation for specific view.

Some fields in form view models often have to be readonly. User could prepare view model and modify these fields, so I must ensure that this will not happen. I protect my application in backend by retrieving entity from database and manually mapping onto it only these fields from viewmodel that should be editable. This is pain in the butt and error prone. Is there better way to do this? Maybe should I make another model for posting back?

Comment: Are you worried about your readonly fields being modified and sent back? Can you not verify that server side when they post it back to you?

Comment: I'm not worried, because I prevent this by mapping only editable fields on entity before updating it. I rather wonder whether there is better way to solve this. It's annoying because I must explicitly define each write mapping and I cannot use AutoMapper to do this without defining field mapping explicitly. I think about making some custom attribute for readonly view model fields and check this attribute in AutoMapper mapping definition, but maybe you have better ideas.

Answer (score 0):

If you want some fields to readonly. You can control it from Angular Controller.

```
//In you Angular Controller 
  $scope.readOnlyForm = true;


//In your HTML angular template
<input type="text" ng-model="modelName" ng-readonly="readOnlyForm">
```

This will make this feild readonly Or you can disable these feilds using

```
ng-disabled="readOnlyForm "
```

As **readOnlyForm**  is true these fields will be readonly.

Comment: I use ng-disabled on client-side but this doesn't protect me from posting back view model with modified read only fields. I must prevent this server-side and my question is whether there is better way than I'm doing it or some best practice in this case.